System.Text.Json deserializing to a class with an object property always yields a JsonElement
I have a class that represents an expression tree with three properties: Left containing either another expression or a discrete value, Operator containing an enumeration of operation types, and Right which can contain another expression or a discrete value.
public class Expr
{
  public object Left { get; set; }
  public OperatorEnum Operator { get; set; }
  public object Right { get; set; }
}

When I deserialize this using System.Text.Json the resulting instance Left and Right properties are always of type JsonElement whether they contain a nested Expr or a discrete value (string, decimal, etc).
i.e. when I deserialize { "Left": "foo", "Operator": "Equals", "Right": "bar" } into instance Expr expr, expr.Left.GetType() always returns JsonElement.
I've built a JsonConverter class and am adding it to the JsonSerializerOptions for both serialization and deserialization, but admittedly, I don't have a lot of experience with it.
namespace Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.Json;
    using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

    public class ExpressionConverter : JsonConverter<Expr>
    {
        public override Expr Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            Expr ret = new Expr();

            bool inLeft = false;
            bool inOper = false;
            bool inRight = false;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (!inLeft && !inOper && !inRight)
                {
                    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                    {
                        if (reader.ValueTextEquals("Left"))
                        {
                            inLeft = true;
                        }
                        else if (reader.ValueTextEquals("Operator"))
                        {
                            inOper = true;
                        }
                        else if (reader.ValueTextEquals("Right"))
                        {
                            inRight = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (inLeft)
                    { 
                        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
                        {
                            string val = reader.GetString();
                            if (val != null) ret.Left = val.ToString();
                            else ret.Left = null;
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
                        {
                            ret.Left = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Expr>(ref reader, options);
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
                        {
                            ret.Left = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<object>>(ref reader, options);
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
                        {
                            ret.Left = reader.GetDecimal();
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.True)
                        {
                            ret.Left = true;
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.False)
                        {
                            ret.Left = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected token type '" + reader.TokenType.ToString() + "' while processing value for 'Left' expression.");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (inOper)
                    {
                        ret.Operator = (OperatorEnum)(Enum.Parse(typeof(OperatorEnum), reader.GetString()));
                    }
                    else if (inRight)
                    {
                        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
                        {
                            string val = reader.GetString();
                            if (val != null) ret.Right = val.ToString();
                            else ret.Left = null;
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
                        {
                            ret.Right = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Expr>(ref reader, options);
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
                        {
                            ret.Right = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<object>>(ref reader, options);
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
                        {
                            ret.Right = reader.GetDecimal();
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.True)
                        {
                            ret.Right = true;
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.False)
                        {
                            ret.Right = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected token type '" + reader.TokenType.ToString() + "' while processing value for 'Left' expression.");
                        }
                    }                        

                    inLeft = false;
                    inOper = false;
                    inRight = false;
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Expr value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

            writer.WriteStartObject();

            if (value.Left is Expr)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName("Left");
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.Left, options);
            }
            else if (IsNumberType(value.Left))
            {
                writer.WriteNumber("Left", Convert.ToDecimal(value.Left));
            }
            else if (IsBooleanType(value.Left))
            {
                writer.WriteBoolean("Left", Convert.ToBoolean(value.Left));
            }
            else
            {
                if (value.Left != null)
                {
                    writer.WriteString("Left", value.Left.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteNull("Left");
                }
            }

            writer.WriteString("Operator", value.Operator.ToString());

            if (value.Right is Expr)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName("Right");
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.Right, options);
            }
            else if (IsNumberType(value.Right))
            {
                writer.WriteNumber("Right", Convert.ToDecimal(value.Right));
            }
            else if (IsBooleanType(value.Right))
            {
                writer.WriteBoolean("Right", Convert.ToBoolean(value.Right));
            }
            else
            {
                if (value.Right != null)
                {
                    writer.WriteString("Right", value.Right.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteNull("Right");
                }
            }

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        private bool IsNumberType(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return false;
            return Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out double _);
        }

        private bool IsBooleanType(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return false;
            return Boolean.TryParse(value.ToString(), out bool _);
        }
    }
}

Is there any way to get the Left and Right properties to correctly reflect the value type after deserialization, e.g. Expr, string, etc?

Have you tried to go generic Expr<TLeft, TRight>?

That's a good idea, and I'll plan to do that down the road.  Need something that will work with this class as is for now.  Thanks for the suggestion

Full solution, in case anyone needs the answer.
namespace Sandbox
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text.Json;
    using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
    using ExpressionTree;

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"{ ""Left"": ""foo"", ""Operator"": ""Equals"", ""Right"": ""bar"" }";
            Expr e = DeserializeJson<Expr>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(e.Left.GetType()); // Should print "System.String"
            Console.WriteLine(e.Right.GetType()); // Should print "System.String"
        }

        static T DeserializeJson<T>(string json)
        {
            JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
            options.Converters.Add(new ExpressionConverter());

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, options);
        }
    }

    public class ExpressionConverter : JsonConverter<Expr>
    {
        public override Expr Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            {
                throw new JsonException("Expected start of object");
            }

            Expr expr = new Expr();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                {
                    return expr;
                }

                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                {
                    string propertyName = reader.GetString();
                    reader.Read();

                    switch (propertyName)
                    {
                        case "Left":
                            expr.Left = ReadValue(ref reader);
                            break;
                        case "Operator":
                            expr.Operator = Enum.Parse<OperatorEnum>(reader.GetString());
                            break;
                        case "Right":
                            expr.Right = ReadValue(ref reader);
                            break;
                        default:
                            reader.Skip();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return expr;
        }

        private object ReadValue(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonTokenType.String:
                    return reader.GetString();
                case JsonTokenType.Number:
                    if (reader.TryGetInt64(out long longValue))
                        return longValue;
                    return reader.GetDouble();
                case JsonTokenType.True:
                    return true;
                case JsonTokenType.False:
                    return false;
                case JsonTokenType.Null:
                    return null;
                case JsonTokenType.StartObject:
                    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Expr>(ref reader, new JsonSerializerOptions { Converters = { new ExpressionConverter() } });
                case JsonTokenType.StartArray:
                    List<object> list = new List<object>();
                    while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                    {
                        list.Add(ReadValue(ref reader));
                    }
                    return list;
                default:
                    throw new JsonException($"Unexpected token type: {reader.TokenType}");
            }
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Expr value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            writer.WritePropertyName("Left");
            WriteValue(writer, value.Left);

            writer.WritePropertyName("Operator");
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.Operator.ToString());

            writer.WritePropertyName("Right");
            WriteValue(writer, value.Right);

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        private void WriteValue(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                writer.WriteNullValue();
            }
            else if (value is string str)
            {
                writer.WriteStringValue(str);
            }
            else if (value is long l)
            {
                writer.WriteNumberValue(l);
            }
            else if (value is int i)
            {
                writer.WriteNumberValue(i);
            }
            else if (value is double d)
            {
                writer.WriteNumberValue(d);
            }
            else if (value is bool b)
            {
                writer.WriteBooleanValue(b);
            }
            else if (value is Expr expr)
            {
                Write(writer, expr, null);
            }
            else if (value is IEnumerable<object> list)
            {
                writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    WriteValue(writer, item);
                }
                writer.WriteEndArray();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new JsonException($"Unexpected value type: {value.GetType()}");
            }
        }
    }
}

